# WordPress post miss schedule with Java

Tags: java, wordpress, schedule

When I enter data for WordPress with function `wp_insert_post` of WordPress, my writings of scheduled can publish.

But if I use Java to enter data entries scheduled for WordPress, it does not publish.

I need to configure how data when I enter with my Java article can publish instead miss schedule